# Firefox and IE render pages larger than chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox

When viewing a page in firefox, it appears much bigger than it does when opened in chrome, as if it has been zoomed in.

Other machines using firefox display the page in the smaller state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had my display set to 125%

Resolution was to go to: control panel -> display 
and set it to 100%.